# Terminal crashes when launching a French spell correcting python script based on fasttext

Tags: python, spell-checking, fasttext, ubuntu-22.04

#### Background

Trying to run the python script for French spelling correction based on `fasttext` (from the tutorial [here](https://blog.reachsumit.com/posts/2020/07/spell-checker-fasttext/)) from the command line.

#### What I have done

- downloaded the `fasttext` [models](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) (bin and text)
- built `fasttext` as a command-line tool:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ make
```

- tried to run the code below

#### Code

`script.py`

```
import io
import fasttext

def load_vectors(fname):
    fin = io.open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n', errors='ignore')
    n, d = map(int, fin.readline().split())
    data = {}
    for line in fin:
        tokens = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        data[tokens[0]] = map(float, tokens[1:])
    return data

def spelltest(tests, model, vocab):
    "Run correction(wrong) on all (right, wrong) pairs; report results."
    import time
    start = time.clock()
    good, unknown = 0, 0
    n = len(tests)
    for right, wrong in tests:
        w = wrong
        if w in vocab:
            print('word: {} exists in the vocabulary. No correction required'.format(w))
        else:
            w_old = w
            w = model.get_nearest_neighbors(w, k=1)[0][1]
            print("found replacement: {} for word: {}".format(w, w_old))
        good += (w == right)
    dt = time.clock() - start
    print('{:.0%} of {} correct at {:.0f} words per second '
          .format(good / n, n, n / dt))

def Testset(lines):
    "Parse 'right: wrong1 wrong2' lines into [('right', 'wrong1'), ('right', 'wrong2')] pairs."
    return [(right, wrong)
            for (right, wrongs) in (line.split(':') for line in lines)
            for wrong in wrongs.split()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = fasttext.load_model("cc.fr.300.bin")
    vocab = load_vectors("cc.fr.300.vec")
    
    spelltest(Testset(open('Memoires_secrets_09.txt')), model, vocab)
    #spelltest(Testset(open('spell-testset2.txt')), model, vocab)
```

#### Error

The terminal throws a warning and crashes when running `script.py`.

```
Warning : `load_model` does not return WordVectorModel or SupervisedModel any more, but a `FastText` object which is very similar.
```

#### Environment

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Python 3.10.4

Comment: That `Warning` doesn't sound like it indicates any 'crash', but a mere advisory that might influence how you use the returned object. What makes you think things crashed? Is there any other output, or suggestion code after your `load_model()` executed at all?

Comment: No, I only received the `Warning`, without any other output. The script was running for about 30 seconds, and then the Terminal closed itself.

Comment: "Terminasl closed itself"? That's not typical behavior in any terminal/shell, in response to any error from something it's executed. Does that happen every time you run your script? How exactly are you invoking the script? How much RAM in the system? (An out-of-memory condition forcing a arbitrary process-kill *might* take out the terminal, rather than the Python process, but I'd not expect that to happen reliably.) What if you add more output to check if your code is reaching/completing your `load_vectors()`, or reaching any parts of your `spellcheck()`?

Comment: Note also: if intending to read `.txt` vectors into native Python dicts/lists/floats, you'll likely get at least 2x, and maybe far more, expansion in Python heap over the 1.1GB size of those vectors on-disk. So that step alone may be using 2-4GB, in addtion to the 4GB+ of the full-model load. Also: your use of `map()` isn't yet applying `float()` to return a list, but returning a `<map object>` that's holding a ref to `tokens[1:]` list, & will apply `float()` when iterated-over. That may consume even more interim RAM, & AFAICT, you don't need to store those vectors at all, just the words.